# How do you transform a Pandas data frame into category and list of items?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to output a task list as PDF. The output should be

- Hallway

  - Task
  - Task
  - Task
- Front Room

  - Task
  - Task
  - Task
- [Room name]

  - Task
  - ...

I have the following Pandas data frame which represents the cleaning tasks that need to occur in each room on a given week.

```
           Room                                           Task Weeks
0       Hallway                                   Vacuum floor  ABCD
2       Hallway                                      Mop floor  ABCD
4    Front Room                                   Vacuum floor  ABCD
5    Front Room                           Empty Vacuum Cleaner  ABCD
6    Front Room  Wipe skirting boards with slightly damp cloth     A
7    Front Room                                      Mop floor  ABCD
8    Front Room      If tablecloth is dirty, change tablecloth  ABCD
10  Living Room                                   Vacuum floor  ABCD
11  Living Room  Wipe skirting boards with slightly damp cloth     A
12  Living Room                                      Tidy sofa  ABCD
```

I have tried groupby

```
today_tasks = (
    task_data[task_data["Weeks"].str.contains(schedule_week)]
    .groupby("Room", group_keys=True)
    .apply(lambda x: x)
)
print(today_tasks.head(10))
```

Which returns the following

```
                                         Room                    Task Weeks
Room                                                                           
Bathroom               62                Bathroom            Vacuum floor  ABCD
                       63                Bathroom               Mop floor  ABCD
                       64                Bathroom              Clean bath  ABCD
                       65                Bathroom      Clean shower heads    AC
                       66                Bathroom      Clean shower glass    AC
                       68                Bathroom            Clean toilet  ABCD
                       69                Bathroom              Clean sink    AC
Front Bedroom Upstairs 45  Front Bedroom Upstairs            Vacuum floor  ABCD
                       46  Front Bedroom Upstairs               Mop floor  ABCD
                       47  Front Bedroom Upstairs  Remove sheets from bed  ABCD
```

I appreciate that I could `for` through and put the data frame into a dictionary, but this does not feel very Pandas-native. Equally, however, the set is only 70 rows long and only needs to be executed weekly, so performance probably does not matter too much. Nonetheless, I do prefer to abide by best practices.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You've basically got it. You've exhausted (IMO) the usefulness of pandas for your outcome in terms of efficiency

Answer (score 1):

You can render HTML template with `jinja2` then convert to PDF with external tool like `wkhtmltopdf` via `pdfkit` library:

```
import jinja2
import io

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)

def render_pdf(filename, **kwargs):
    template = templateEnv.get_template('template.html')
    output = template.render(**kwargs)
    return output

for week, subdf in df.groupby('Weeks'):
    room_tasks = subdf.groupby('Room')['Task'].agg(list).to_dict()
    print(render_html(week=week, room_tasks=room_tasks))
```

Output:

```html
<!-- Week A -->
<html>
<title>Week A</title>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>Front Room</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Wipe skirting boards with slightly damp cloth</li>
  </ul> 
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Living Room</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Wipe skirting boards with slightly damp cloth</li>
  </ul> 
</ul>
</body>
</html>

<!-- Week ABCD -->
<html>
<title>Week ABCD</title>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>Front Room</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Vacuum floor</li>
  </ul><ul>
    <li>Empty Vacuum Cleaner</li>
  </ul><ul>
    <li>Mop floor</li>
  </ul><ul>
    <li>If tablecloth is dirty, change tablecloth</li>
  </ul> 
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Hallway</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Vacuum floor</li>
  </ul><ul>
    <li>Mop floor</li>
  </ul> 
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Living Room</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Vacuum floor</li>
  </ul><ul>
    <li>Tidy sofa</li>
  </ul> 
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

`template.html`

```
<html>
<title>Week {{ week }}</title>
<body>
{%- for room, tasks in room_tasks.items() %}
<ul>
  <li>{{ room }}</li>
  {% for task in tasks -%}
  <ul>
    <li>{{ task }}</li>
  </ul>
  {%- endfor %} 
</ul>
{%- endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```